# R - Use regex to remove all strings, special characters, and pattern ending element

Tags: regex, r

Say I have a character vector `ids` as follows:

```
ids <- c("367025001", "CT_341796001", "M13X01692-01", "13C025050901", "13C00699551")
```

I want to search each element and remove all letters, all special characters, and "01" when it ends the element. So `ids` would become:

```
ids_replaced <- c("3670250", "3417960", "1301692", "130250509", "1300699551")
```

I'm coming out somewhat close, but it hasn't worked as I've intended it to.

```
gsub("(.*?)(\\d+?)(01$)", "\\2", ids, perl = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
gsub("01$|\\D", "", ids)
# [1] "3670250"    "3417960"    "1301692"    "130250509"  "1300699551"
identical(gsub("01$|\\D", "", ids), ids_replaced)
# [1] TRUE
```

[Regular Expression Explanation:](http://regexdoc.com/re/explain.pl)

- `01` matches "01"
- `$` before an optional `\n`, and the end of the string
- `|` OR
- `\D` matches non-digits (all but 0-9)

Answer (score 1):

Using [rex](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rex/index.html) may make this type of task a little simpler.

```
ids <- c("367025001", "CT_341796001", "M13X01692-01", "13C025050901", "13C00699551")

re_substitutes(ids,
  rex(non_digits %or% list("01", end)),
  '',
  global = TRUE)

#> [1] "3670250"    "3417960"    "1301692"    "130250509"  "1300699551"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Hadn't heard of `rex`. I'll check it out, though I do want to learn regular expressions.

Comment: the output of all `rex()` calls is a regular expression, so one way to learn might be to construct regular expressions using `rex()` and see what it creates!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do it in R but you can use this regex:

```
-\d+$|\D
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/eU3sS3/1)**

[image]